# Getting err no exports found in module when deployed to vercel

Tags: node.js, module, sequelize.js, vercel, sequelize-cli

I deployed my nodejs server with sequelize and sequelize cli, when I deploy application to vercel with having folder only index.js in models which is sequelize-cli default folder and file, my app is working fine but when I add new file, for example, quote.js to models folder and after redopley my node app, vercel giving me err saying that **No exports found in module "../index.js".**, **Did you forget to export a function or a server?** But when I run my nodejs locally, it's working fine. So, I notices what exactly causing problem but couldn't find solution how to solve it. Can someone help me to solve this issue? plssss

folder structure:

-server
-config
-models -> there're two files in this folder index.js and Quote.js, Quote.js is causing problem when it's deployed to vercel.
-routes
index.js

Quote.js file:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => { 
  
  const Quote = sequelize.define("Quote", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }); 
  return Quote;
};
```

index.js file:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Actually, problem is not really big but quite annoying.